# How to add/tag unchartable data to multiline chart tooltips on ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a multi-line (multiple dataset) chart with things like hi and lo temperature for days in months. The API I'm using sends the temps along with a formatted date like "Thursday, August 8". I'm using custom tooltips and I need a way to append this formatted date to each data point's tooltip so the day shows on a point's tooltip on hover.

Ive implemented custom tooltips per ChartJS documentation to allow me to include weather icons in the tooltip, but these icons were named with numbers (like 4.svg), so that was easier since numbers are chartable data while day of the week names aren't. I can't find any leads for how to approach the day/date addition.

Unfortunately I don't have a runnable snippet due to the complexity of the graph and functions running it. But this is more of an abstract question of how to add non chartable data to chartJS while still having it tagged to the x-axis somehow so I can show it on tooltips on hover.

Expected result is a tooltip that pops up upon hovering a point in the chart that contains the following:

1. The data from all datasets at that x-axis value (working)
2. The weather icon for that specific x-axis value (working)
3. The day such as "Thursday" or something similar (not working)

Any help on how to get non-numerical, non-chartable data that is tied to data points onto chartJS tooltips?

Comment: There is a custom tooltip example for chartJS [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips).

Comment: Yes, I used that template to create a custom tooltip - I just dont know how to have something like "Thursday, August 8" and "Friday, August 9" attached to specific point tooltips since they are strings and not numerical chartable data.

Comment: I would check in your tooltip callback function whether the "data" parameter that gets passed in contains your extra fields.  If not you might need to dig them out of the original dataset returned from your api call.